# Android: Force close on connectivity change during a download

Tags: android, android-asynctask, connectivity

So, I'm loading an URL with Asynctask and I've handled all the possible connectivity problems before the download starts, but now my app force closes when switching from data to wifi while downloading. So the question is:

Will I have to do the Asynctask on a Service or is there a way pausing it and resuming when there is a connection available? I already have a receiver which starts downloading right after there is connectivity:

```
    if (isOnline()) {
        getData();
    } else {
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(
                "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE");
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (isOnline()) {
                    unregisterReceiver(this);
                    getData();
                }
            }
        }, intentFilter);
    }
```

But how can I resume Asynctask after connectivity is available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely you want to do in the background on a service. Might I suggest looking at the documentation for the [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) class? By doing this in a service, you don't have to mess around with all the nastiness of making sure to you cleanup the AsyncTask stuff in the Activity. And the service will continue to run in the background until the download is finished.

Comment: Thanks for great answer. Here's a useful tutorial I found if someone else needs it too: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-fundamentals-intentservice-basics/

Comment: Another question, if you don't mind: the download still doesn't complete when connection changes while loading. Otherwise it works fine. How to know if the download was interrupted? Do I register a Connectivity Change Receiver in the onCreate method and fire up the download method every time connectivity changes and when it's completed set a boolean false to let the receiver know the download succeeded? There must be easier way.

Comment: @Liro that's probably best asked as another questions on here :) I know if I saw it I'd vote it up and try to answer it ;)

Comment: Well here you go Kurtis.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7827631/handling-connection-change-while-loading-data-with-intentservice