# Handling connection change while loading data with IntentService

Tags: android

So I have a small little app which downloads a very small amount of data from the net. Everything else works just fine and downloads properly, but when connection changes (I lose wifi range) the download won't complete and the user doesn't get their data.

I have an idea how to handle this. I set up a BroadcastReceiver on my main Activity which communicates with my IntentService. When the IntentService completes the download, I then unregister the receiver. To top all this, I set up a Broadcastreceiver to listen connectivity changes and if connection is available, and if there is a connection, the main activity sends an Intent to start the download. See here:

Main Activity:

```
public class Sample extends Activity {
    private BroadcastReceiver connectivityReceiver;
    private ResponseReceiver receiver;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle sis){
        super.onCreate(sis);


    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(
            "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE");
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (Network.isOnline()) {
                fireUpDownloadingIntent();
            }
        }
        }, intentFilter);


    }

    public class ResponseReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        public static final String ACTION_RESP = "com.irough.intent.action.URL_LOADED";

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
              if(intent.getBooleanExtra(DLService.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE, false) {
                  unRegisterReceiver(connectivityReceiver);
              }
        }

    }
}
```

DLService.java:

```
public class DLService extends IntentService {
    public static final String DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE = "dlc";

    public DLService() {
        super("DLService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
        broadcastIntent.setAction(ResponseReceiver.ACTION_RESP);

    broadcastIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        broadcastIntent.putExtra(DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE, true);
        sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);

    }

}
```

The code about should work just fine, but is there an easier or better way to do it? Doesn't have to be done on Service, Asynctask force closes on me when connection drops and that's why put the download action to a service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you lose the connection in your download, I imagine your download will throw some sort of exception. If I were, I'd simply notify the user (using the [android notification api](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)), and give them the option to try to redownload the data.

Preferably though, (and contrary to my previous post in a similar question), you could use my new favorite class in the android, the [AsyncTaskLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html). It sounds like it exactly fits the bill for what you want to do here. Bascially, if there's an error downloading, just have your loader return null. Then in your onLoaderFinished hook in your activity, do what ever you need to do in regards to informing the user. Note that this class is only available to API levels 3 and above, but can still be accessed by lower API levels through the [android compatibility package](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html).

Comment: Yes, I could do that easily. However my app is supposed to be a "give a closest phone number based on lovation" app, so at least I would like to have the user see as least "could not do this, click again" prompts as possible.

Comment: Edited my post to address your comment